# Delayed output stream "manipulator"

Tags: c++, c++11, stream

I was just playing around with some code and had the idea about writing some kind of `ostream` manipulator to delay the output of characters in a typewriter like style.

The focus was mostly on how to use it and was inspired by `std::fixed` or `std::setprecision`.

Overall it works pretty well. I just want to make sure that I didn't miss anything that may backfire any time.

The code is just for playing around and doesn't have a real use case (yet).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <thread>

namespace manip
{
    struct delayed : std::ostream, std::streambuf
    {
        std::ostream* m_postream;
        std::chrono::milliseconds m_ms;

        delayed(std::chrono::milliseconds ms)
            : std::ostream(this)
            , m_postream(nullptr)
            , m_ms(ms)
        {}

        delayed(std::ostream& o, std::chrono::milliseconds ms)
            : std::ostream(this)
            , m_postream(&o)
            , m_ms(ms)
        {}

        int overflow(int c) override
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(m_ms);
            if (m_postream)
            {
                (*m_postream) << (char)c;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        friend delayed& operator<<(std::ostream&, delayed&&);
    };

    delayed& operator<<(std::ostream& o, delayed&& d)
    {
        delayed* delayed_ostream = dynamic_cast<delayed*>(&o);
        if (delayed_ostream)
        {
            d.m_postream = delayed_ostream->m_postream;
        }
        else
        {
            d.m_postream = &o;
        }
        return d;
    }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    using namespace manip;

    std::cout 
        << delayed(200ms) << "Wake up Neo."             << delayed(1100ms) << std::endl
        << delayed(200ms) << "The Matrix has you."      << delayed(3100ms) << std::endl
        << delayed(200ms) << "Follow the white Rabbit." << delayed(1100ms) << std::endl;
}
```

As it seems my intention on what `delayed` should do and how it works weren't very clear. So here is what the example will do as instructions:

```
//delayed(200ms) is passed to the stream: delay all following characters by 200ms
<wait 200ms><print 'W'>
<wait 200ms><print 'a'>
<wait 200ms><print 'k'>
<wait 200ms><print 'e'>
<wait 200ms><print ' '>
<wait 200ms><print 'u'>
<wait 200ms><print 'p'>
<wait 200ms><print ' '>
<wait 200ms><print 'N'>
<wait 200ms><print 'e'>
<wait 200ms><print 'o'>
<wait 200ms><print '.'>
//delayed(1100ms) is passed to the stream: delay all following characters by 1100ms
<wait 1100ms><print endl>
//delayed(200ms) is passed to the stream: delay all following characters by 200ms
<wait 200ms><print 'T'>
<wait 200ms><print 'h'>
<wait 200ms><print 'e'>
<wait 200ms><print ' '>
<wait 200ms><print 'M'>
<wait 200ms><print 'a'>
<wait 200ms><print 't'>
<wait 200ms><print 'r'>
<wait 200ms><print 'i'>
<wait 200ms><print 'x'>
<wait 200ms><print ' '>
<wait 200ms><print 'h'>
<wait 200ms><print 'a'>
<wait 200ms><print 's'>
<wait 200ms><print ' '>
<wait 200ms><print 'y'>
<wait 200ms><print 'o'>
<wait 200ms><print 'u'>
<wait 200ms><print '.'>
//delayed(3100ms) is passed to the stream: delay all following characters by 3100ms
<wait 3100ms><print endl>
//delayed(200ms) is passed to the stream: delay all following characters by 200ms
<wait 200ms><print 'F'>
<wait 200ms><print 'o'>
<wait 200ms><print 'l'>
<wait 200ms><print 'l'>
<wait 200ms><print 'o'>
<wait 200ms><print 'w'>
<wait 200ms><print ' '>
<wait 200ms><print 't'>
<wait 200ms><print 'h'>
<wait 200ms><print 'e'>
<wait 200ms><print ' '>
<wait 200ms><print 'w'>
<wait 200ms><print 'h'>
<wait 200ms><print 'i'>
<wait 200ms><print 't'>
<wait 200ms><print 'e'>
<wait 200ms><print ' '>
<wait 200ms><print 'R'>
<wait 200ms><print 'a'>
<wait 200ms><print 'b'>
<wait 200ms><print 'b'>
<wait 200ms><print 'i'>
<wait 200ms><print 't'>
<wait 200ms><print '.'>
//delayed(1100ms) is passed to the stream: delay all following characters by 1100ms
<wait 1100ms><print endl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one improvement myself by altering the `operator<<` function into:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, delayed&& d)
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    delayed* delayed_ostream = dynamic_cast<delayed*>(&o);
    if (d.m_ms == 0ms)
    {
        if (delayed_ostream)
        {
            return *delayed_ostream->m_postream;
        }
        else
        {
            return o;
        }
    }
    if (delayed_ostream)
    {
        d.m_postream = delayed_ostream->m_postream;
    }
    else
    {
        d.m_postream = &o;
    }
    return d;
}
```

This will minimize the effect of `delayed` when it is used to disable the delay by using `delayed(0ms)`.

Example:

```
std::cout << delayed(200ms) << "Slow..." << delayed(0ms) << "Fast..." << delayed(200ms) << "Slow..." << std::endl;
```

The part `"Fast..."` will be printed immediately without any indirection through the `delay` object.